# Merge doesn't reflect in Derby database immediately

Tags: jpa, merge, derby

I have the following code which I call from the front end

```
public Login update(Login i) {
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Login result=infoDAO.update(i);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return result;
}

public Login update(Login i) {
    return em.merge(i);
}
```

I have

```
private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HRTool-JPA");
protected EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
```

The methods are being called and the values are passed to the DB correctly(I am using Apache derby) but I can see the new changed values in the DB only after I disconnect and reconnect to it. Am I missing some step after merge ? I am new to JPA and appreciate any suggestions on the same

Comment: (1) If you have **autocommit** off; (2) bypassing the used caching entity manager and accessing the stale database.

Comment: Where should I check if autocommit is on/off? Sorry, I am a newbie to JPA

Comment: Sorry, autocommit is on by default (JDBC standard); here I feel it should more be _off_, but for the error _on_ is fine. @bryce is right to lay the error at the entity manager's caching/postponements.

Comment: errm, so what is "infoDAO" and what is in commitAndCloseTransaction() ? The JPA provider is what decides about "autoCommit" not the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Hibernate keep the requests in its cache and Hibernate decides when it wants to execute them.

You can try to add a em.flush() after em.merge() 
It will execute all the requests left in its cache.

Comment: I am using EclipseLink, is the same applicable?

Comment: I think yes: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_flush.htm
 If this works for you don't forget to accept my answer ;-)

Comment: @user2017810 - "but I can see the new changed values in the DB only after I disconnect and reconnect to it. " - surely then this is an issue with your DB client and refreshing the data there, and nothing to do with JPA?